# Javascript Event Listener on table rows fire multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table created with html and JS.When a row is clicked, certain data is being captured and sent to another function. Problem is the clickableRow() function does a weird behaviour. On first click it does nothing, on second click it triggers twice, on third click - three time, on fifth,sixth and so on it triggers more than 20-30 times.
The culprit function that deals with data extraction looks like this.

```
function clickableRow(){
        const selectTr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
        for(items of selectTr){
            items.addEventListener("click",e=>{
                var wholeRow = e.toElement.parentElement.innerText;
                var stringArray = wholeRow.split(/(\s+)/);
                var whichTable = e.path[4].id;
                if (stringArray[0].localeCompare("ServiceID") == 0 ||
                    stringArray[0].localeCompare("VisitID") == 0 ||
                    stringArray[0].localeCompare("Vehicle") == 0){
                    // do nothing. this is in case column header is clicked when sorting.
                } else {
                    sendDataToRightPane(stringArray[0], whichTable);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

HTML table code:

```
<div id="checkServices" style="display:block">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
                <th class="service" data-column="id" data-order="desc">ServiceID &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.id" data-order="desc">VisitID &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.vehicle.licensePlate" data-order="desc">License Plate &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Order &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Status &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair End Date &#9660</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="serviceOrdersTable">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Javascript function that builds the table from Ajax request:

```
function buildServiceOrdersTable(data) {
        var table = document.getElementById('serviceOrdersTable')
        table.innerHTML = ''
        var text = "To Be Implemented"
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row = `<tr onclick="clickableRow()">
                    <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].visit.id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].visit.vehicle.licensePlate}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].service.name}</td>
                    <td>${text}</td>
                    <td>${text}</td>
                    </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row
        }
    }
```

I have read multiple threads about eventlisteners firing more than once, but none of them are in a loop like mine and therefore I cannot put my finger exactly on where the bug can be fixed from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<tr onclick="clickableRow()">` *every* time you click on the row you add a new event handler for the row. Don't mix archaic html events (`onclick=`) with js events (`.addEventListener`). Remove the `onclick=` and add `clickableRow()` at the end of `buildServiceOrdersTable()`  (or don't add event handler within clickableRow as that *is* the event handler)

Comment: Never ever add javascript in a html string.... `div.innerHTML = "<div onclick='...'">`. This is why we have `addEventListener` in the first place....

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response and for the additional information. It works just fine. I will look more into what you wrote on how eventhandlers and onclick functions work and can/can't coexist together. Again thank you !